# Time vs. Ensemble Distribution of Sample Mean Z-Scores

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, central-limit-theorem

Suppose we have a sequence of bounded i.i.d variables $\lbrace X_n \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with unit variance and zero mean. Let $\bar X_n$ denote the sample mean of the first $n$ variables in the sequence. From the central limit theorem we have that,

$$Z_n = \sqrt{n} \cdot \bar X_n \to_{\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

What about the uniform distributions over the elements $S_n = \lbrace Z_k \rbrace_{k \le n}$ which are the set of the Z-scores up to a certain time? Effectively, I'm wondering about the long-run distribution of the Z-scores.

At first, I thought this might also converge to the standard normal, but this doesn't seem to be the case. See the plots below where I show the histogram associated with the sequence of Z-scores. From this, I suspect that the time average might actually be a random limiting distribution. What's the actual situation? **Is there a way to characterize the long-term behavior of the time average for the Z-scores?** My guess is that the distribution for,

$$h_{a,b} \sim \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} | \lbrace k \in [0,T] : S_k / \sqrt{k} \in [a,b] \rbrace |$$

has singularities in its PDF at the points $\lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$ since this is the case for $h_{0,\infty}$ which is arcsine distributed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can show that there is no stationary distribution for the $Z_n$ as defined in your question. Consider a simple quadrature $\mathcal{Q} = ((-\infty, 0], (0, \infty))$. Then the liklihood of seeing a particular histogram (as characterized by positive sojourn time) is given by the distribution of,

$$H(0, \infty) = \frac{1}{T} | \lbrace k \in [0,T] : S_k > 0 \rbrace |$$

This random variable follows an [arcsine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_laws_(Wiener_process)#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20the%20arcsine,to%20Paul%20L%C3%A9vy%20(1939).). This is also not hard to show empirically.

[image]

A process with an ergodic limit obeys the law of large numbers and would have an empirical function that looks as though it was converging to a Dirac delta function. From this, we conclude that the z-scores do not 'mix' well.

Some last comments. [Paul Levy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_L%C3%A9vy_(mathematician)) first formulated the arcsine law used above. The style of argument presented above is loosely related to [local-times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_time_(mathematics)), another of Levy's contributions and a powerful device used in the analysis of integrated stochastic processes. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08912#:%7E:text=These%20notes%20contains%20an%20introduction,of%20regulated%20stochastic%20differential%20equations.) is a somewhat accessible simple introduction. The arcsine appears elsewhere. [Erdos showed](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01817702.pdf) the distribution of prime divisors satisfies an arcsine law.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution of the long run average of the Z transforms (Z scores) is exactly the same as that of the original variable up to a parameter change.

Explicitly, if the original averages converges in probability to a normal distribution with a given mean and standard deviation, the average of the Z transforms will converge to a normal distribution with expectation 0 and variance 1.

To see this, it is necessary to write down what it means for the average to converge in distribution to a normal variable. This means that the limit of the probability that the average will be below a given value converges to the cumulative distribution function of a normal with a certain mean and variance. If you take the limit in probability of the average of the Z transforms being below a given value $X$, this will be equivalent to the average being below $\sigma X + \mu$. This in turn implies that the average of the Z transforms converges in distribution to the same distribution as the original averages, up to a rescaling of the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Your answer currently isn’t meeting the criteria for the bounty. I think you’re saying that you can use the Lyapunov CLT to show convergence, but don’t provide details or a reference. I’m also curious about the long-run distribution (question title) which I don’t think is addressed here.

Comment: Long run distribution = convergence of the distribution (as time goes to infinity), which is addressed. No, I’m more like saying: $if$ you’re under the conditions of the CLT, then the Z score average will behave in a similar way to the normal averages (because it is a linear transformation)

Comment: See my answer. This is closer to what I was looking for. Of course, I was hoping someone might add more detail than what I was able to find through literature search.

Comment: Then you’re not in the conditions of the CLT if you’re not getting convergence of the Z scores. The way your question was phrased, it implies that the averages converge since you’re the conditions of the CLT, but the Z scores do not converge under the same CLT conditions